# textarea update not working with ajax submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea field where some data already exist

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="message" id="editor1">There is some lines with basic html tags like strong,underline</textarea>
```

If I change above to like this

```html
<textarea name="message" id="editor1">Some new lines with basic html tags like strong,underline</textarea>
```

But after submit action Everything works fine but I always get old textarea data not new updated data.

While js code

```
$(document).on('click', ".send-mail", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var s_message=$("textarea[name=message]").val();




    $('#send_mail').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}).one('click', '#sendmail', function () {
        sendMail(s_message);

    });
});
function sendMail(s_message) {

    jQuery.ajax({

        url: 'request/sendmail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: s_message,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                $("#notify .message").html("<strong>" + data.status + "</strong>: " + data.message);
                $("#notify").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success").fadeIn();
                $("html, body").scrollTop($("body").offset().top);

            } else {
                $("#notify .message").html("<strong>" + data.status + "</strong>: " + data.message);
                $("#notify").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-danger").fadeIn();
                $("html, body").scrollTop($("body").offset().top);

            }

        }

    });

}
</script>
```

I need new updated data to a PHP Post variable. Why it is not working?

Comment: what about `.send-mail` , `#notify`, `.message`? i didn't see any coding regarding that classes.

Comment: @Piyush could you please post a bit more of your code?

Comment: Also at last you write  `I need new updated data to a PHP Post variable. Why it is not working?` it seems you ave problem in your php code. So it's confusing

Comment: Js does not show any problems at first glance. Need to see php code.

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas It has a POST_['varriable'];

Comment: Problem is in this code, php works fine if I use <input type="text" name="message"

Comment: @Anant .send-mail , #notify, .message are div ids and classes, my question straight it is not working only with textarea update. It works fine with input type="text"; var s_message=$("input[name=message]").val();

Comment: if you want to change text area value when ajax get response, then either use textarea id or class  to update it's value.

Comment: @Anant You can post your answer